# To return STRING type using MYSQL function

Tags: mysql, sql, function, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I want to return a string using mysql function.
Code is given below. I gets only boolean 1 or 0 output.

here

> specification_value

is string type

```
CREATE DEFINER=`ranju`@`%` FUNCTION `get_fuel_name`(v_id INT) RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
    RETURN EXISTS (SELECT  `specification_value` FROM  `vehicle_specifications` WHERE  `specification_id` =1 AND `vehicle_id` =v_id LIMIT 1);
END
```

Please find a solution

Comment: You are returning `RETURN EXISTS` and `EXISTS` returns a Boolean `true or false / 1,0`

Answer (score 3):

Change the `exists` sentence, `exists` will evaluate the expression and return only boolean value.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_fuel_name`(v_id INT) 
RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET latin1
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

   RETURN coalesce( (SELECT  `specification_value` 
                      FROM  `vehicle_specifications` 
                      WHERE  `specification_id` =1 
                      AND `vehicle_id` =v_id LIMIT 1
                     ), '');
END
```

It will return empty string if records doesn't exists